# Guarantee that model is associated to same parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Assuming i have 3 models associated to each other:

```
class Farm < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :horses
  has_many :events
end

class Horse < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :farm
  has_many :events_horses, class_name: 'Event::EventsHorse'
  has_many :events, through: :events_horses, source: :event, dependent: :destroy
end

class Event
  belongs_to :farm
  has_many :events_horses, class_name: 'Event::EventsHorse'
  has_many :horses, through: :events_horses, source: :horse, dependent: :destroy
end

class Event::EventsHorse < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = "events_horses"

  belongs_to :horse
  belongs_to :event

  audited associated_with: :event, except: [:id, :event_id]
end
```

How to guarantee that each of the Horse belongs to same Farm as event? Possible solution is using custom validation, but i was wondering if there is some other way. I have few other models like Horse, so it force me to do custom validation method to each of them.

```
class Event
  ...
  validate :horses_belongs_to_farm

  private

  def horses_belongs_to_farm
    horses.all? {|h| h.farm_id == farm_id}
  end   
end
```

Comment: I've fixed it. It should be events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the model you are using is setting up too many id's between the tables that require consistency checking.

If you set the model up this way, then you don't need to validate that a horse's farm and event are consistent since the data ensures it:

```
class Farm < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :horses
  has_many :events
end

class Horse < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :farm
  has_many :events, through: :farm
end

class Event < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :farm
  has_many :horses, through: :farm
end
```

If you need efficient access to horses from events or events from horses, you can use joins. This gives some simplicity, clarity, and consistency.

You should also have a look at [Choosing Between `has_many_through` and `has_and_belongs_to_many`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many).

---

**[Edit based upon updated question and comments]** Now that your model and question are a little more clear, my hunch is that putting the validation in the `Event` model causes redundant validations. Since your intent is to make sure that, in a given event, the horse and farm are consistent, I would put the validation in `EventsHorses`:

```
class Event::EventsHorse < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  validate :horse_belongs_to_farm

  private

  def horse_belongs_to_farm
    horse.farm_id == event.farm_id 
  end   
end
```

As an aside, thy do you have `Event::EventsHorse` rather than simply have a separate model for `EventsHorse`?

Comment: thanks for help! I'm actually simplified the question to be more understandable.
I have "has many through" already 

`has_many :events_horses, class_name: 'Event::EventsHorse'
has_many :horses, through: :events_horses, source: :horse, dependent: :destroy`

I needed "events_horses" for other purpose, but i don't know how to implement your approch into this.

Comment: @irondnb please update (edit) your original question with the actual code you have,  including your events-horses model , and to reword your question so that it is asking what you really wish to know. Otherwise, it's very unclear and other readers won't see your intent. My hunch is that my answer will still apply but with some details added. The `has_and_belongs_to_many` makes "events-horses" relationship *implicit*, but you want it *explicit*. Have a look at: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many.

Comment: I do understand difference and i needed `has_many through` ( can explain why ) Sorry for my inconvenience, but this is my second question here. I've updated the question code. My question still relate to problem.

Comment: Thx for resovling my problem, but i don't understand your last question about `Event::EventsHorse`. 
I like namespacing my models, but if you ask why has_many through other then habtm - It was required for tracking asociacion deletion (https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited), which works only with `has_many through`

Comment: @irondnb you are namespacing your `EventsHorse` an `Event` namespace but there doesn't seem to be any more bias of `EventsHorse` toward `Event` than towards `Horse`. I guess it's somewhat arbitrary as you could have namespaced it as `Horse::EventsHorse`. You didn't namespace your `Event` or `Horse` models. `EventsHorse` is squarely between the two with no stronger relation toward one than the other. It does no harm, I was just curious as to why you had done that.

Comment: Yes, you're right, but i'm planning to namespace `Horse` into `Event` as well. Will it be more coherent then?

Comment: You can do it. I'm not convinced it adds clarity.